# Bash MySQL splitting file location

Tags: mysql, database, bash, scripting

New to bash. I am getting data from a table. How do I get the location of the file. I can’t get the file name because files are in different locations.

```
    v=‘/home/pi/images/bird.png’
    file_only=$(basename ${v})
    Returns bird.png
```

How do I get the /home/pi/x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirname` is the command to get the file path.

```
v="/home/pi/images/bird.png"
dirname "$v"
```

To get the filename only use `basename "$v"` and to get the filename without extension use `basename "$v" .png`

You also can get the same strings using parameter expansion (see `man bash`):

- pathname: `echo ${v%/*}`
- filename: `echo ${v##*/}`

Comment: Thanks.  New to bash so I only know a little.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this for getting file location
`dirname ${v}`

Comment: Thanks.  New to bash so I only know a little.